# SQL query - attempting to display results based on certain conditions using AND/OR and JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

Attempting to display all proposals in the system as long as they satisfy the following conditions:

- the source must be supervisor
- the status_code in the record table must not be 8 or 3

I have attempted a number of way in trying to make this work but I keep getting different data back which is not what I want.

The problem is how the tables have been set up. In theory a proposal can be applied for by a student and if that happens a record is automatically added to the 'record' table with a status set to '6' for pending. This status is then changed a number of times throughout the application process.

What I need is to show the users all proposals which have not been taken. The status codes to indicate this is '3' (accepted by a student so another student cannot take it) and '8' (not available). 
NOTE: not all proposals may have a record in this table (a student has not applied for them)

This is the query so far which satisfies the first condition of being a "supervisor"

```
SELECT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, 
p.description, u.user_record_id, u.forename, 
u.surname, c.course_title, r.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_title) AS tags 
FROM proposal p 
      LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_record_id = p.user_record_id
      LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
      LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
      LEFT JOIN record r on r.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      WHERE p.source = "Supervisor"
      GROUP BY p.proposal_id
```

My attempt at getting it to display all records which are available:

```
SELECT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, 
p.description, u.user_record_id, u.forename, 
u.surname, c.course_title, r.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_title) AS tags 
FROM proposal p 
      LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_record_id = p.user_record_id
      LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
      LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
      LEFT JOIN record r on r.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      WHERE p.source = "Supervisor"
      AND (r.status_code != 3 OR r.status_code !=8)
      GROUP BY p.proposal_id
```

The above query still returns proposals with the status code 3 and it fails to display any proposals which have yet not been applied for.

SQLFiddle Generated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b89a9/1/0

Any help would be much appreciated guys! Thank you.

Comment: Try changing "AND (r.status_code != 3 OR r.status_code !=8)" to "AND (r.status_code not in (3,8) )

Comment: `3 != 3 => false`, `3 != 8 => true`, so `false OR true` is `true`

Comment: @dbinns66 that does successfully return those with status codes that are not 3 or 8 but how would i return all the proposals which do not have status codes since they have not been applied for and therefore are available

Comment: @RoyalBg how would that fit into the current query. thanks

Comment: @user610 - not sure I follow, NULL would not be 3 or 8 and since you're doing LEFT JOIN it should return records with r.status being NULL - can you put together an sqlfiddle for this with create's and data?

Comment: @dbinns66 i have removed all the other tables which are in the main query because they're not needed for this specific bit. here is the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b89a9/1/0 as you can see it only returns those proposals which have status' which are not 3 or 8. does not return those which do not have a record. In total i have 7 proposals in the table. 1 which is unavailable and 1 which is source "student" so it should display 5 but displays 3. hope you can help!

Comment: @user610 - you have 7 records in proposal, 1 is source Student (now 6), 2 have status of 3 or 8 (now 4) and one which is unavailable (now 3) ... the query returns 3 rows... again, not sure I understand what the issue is, you don't have any proposals that don't have a `record` record...

Comment: @dbinns66. Thanks for looking. the one proposal which has a status of 3 or 8 is the same proposal so that would be classed as 1 proposal since its the same. it should return proposal id 3 and 6 also since that does not have a record in the table.

Comment: @dbinns66 summary: I have 7 records in proposal, 1 is source Student (now 6), 1 has a status of 3 or 8 (now 5). 2 which do not have a row in record (proposal id 3 and 6) and 3 which are in record (proposal id 2,5 and 51)

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I was missing a OR statement to achieve my goal.

To get the end result i needed, the query was modified to:

```
SELECT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, u.user_record_id, u.forename, u.surname, c.course_title, r.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag_title) AS tags FROM proposal p 
      LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_record_id = p.user_record_id
      LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
      LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
      LEFT JOIN record r on r.proposal_id = p.proposal_id
      WHERE p.source = "Supervisor"
      AND (r.status_code not in (3,8) OR r.status_code IS NULL)
      GROUP BY p.proposal_id
```

Successfully brings back all proposals which are available, are from the supervisor and those which have no record in the 'record' table.

Thank you to everyone who helped